# Server not repsonding after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: ubuntu

I have a server that was running Ubuntu 8.04. I upgraded Ubuntu via the command-line and got no warning messages. After it was done the server restarted but now I am unable to SSH back in. My site is also not resolving.

My guess is I overwrote something important.

What are some trouble-shooting steps I can take? I am able to execute commands through my VPS provider's admin interface.

I'm not sure what version it upgraded me to honestly.

Answer (score 1):

First, I hope you made backups of your data.

Now, really for your first step, from the console, I would suggest going through these tasks:

1. Update packages, and check for missing dependencies
2. Make sure SSH2 is installed
3. Make sure that you've granted yourself SSH access

More details...
From the console:

1) Updating Packages, and checking for missing dependencies

- apt-get check
- apt-get update

2) Installing / fixing SSH:

- sshd -v (if you have it installed, the first line of output should look something like this:

> OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010

If you don't have it installed, run:

- apt-get install openssh-server
- /etc/init.d/sshd start

Now, make sure that sshd starts when the system is rebooted by running "update-rc.d"

3) Review settings in /etc/ssh/ssh_config

This should at least get you SSH access to the server, and then you can begin restoring your server.

Good luck,
David